# Cannot take picture using OpenCV with Raspberry Pi 4 ssh

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am running OpenCV on my Raspberry Pi using ssh. I have connected a camera, but it’s not taking the image.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

cam_port = 0
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_port)

result, image = cam.read()


if result:
    cv2.imshow("img", image)
    cv2.imwrite("imasdf.png", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow("img")
else:
    print("No image detected. Please! try again")
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ai/bacterium.py", line 10, in <module>
    cv2.imshow("img", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:1272: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'
```

I have libgtk2.0-dev installed. When I run the install command for libgtk2.0-dev I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libgtk2.0-dev is already the newest version (2.24.33-2+rpt1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

I run the file again, and I still get the same error.

Comment: The diagnostic seemed pretty clear. Use tools like `ldd` to show us, in the question, why you're _certain_ that `libgtk2.0-dev` is definitely available to the app.

Comment: I added it to my question now. I still get the error.

Comment: Using graphics with SSH requires a local X server and the `-X` argument. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12755

Comment: You need to install pkg-config if you are using Ubuntu or Debian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since I was connecting to my Raspberry Pi via ssh, I couldn't use imshow.

This is my code now:

```
import cv2

cam_port = 0
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(cam_port)

result, image = cam.read()

cv2.imwrite("imasdf.png", image)
```

Comment: What did you use instead? What did you change? What is the gist of the solution?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Just FYI, the gist of the solution is not to try to display the image on the screen using **OpenCV** `cv.imshow()` which requires an X11 server, and just save the image to disk instead.

Comment: If the machine you are using to `ssh` into the RasPi has X11 (e.g. it is Linux, or a Mac with XQuartz, or Windows with MobaXterm I think), you can try `ssh -X raspberrypi` or `ssh -Y raspberrypi` and your original code may work - test by running `xclock` on RasPi when connected via `ssh`.